# Does flutter support display p3 color profile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, color-profile

Colours in a flutter app look very dull and by default seem to only be in sRGB. How can I implement display P3 to access the wide colors available on all iOS displays.

So far I haven't found any settings to enable this which is bizarre as Flutter markets itself as a framework able to match the quality of native code and be able to design 'beautiful UIs.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news ! They added Display P3 wide gamut colors profile to Flutter 4 days ago ! :)

Link : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55092#issuecomment-1446790646

Add this :

```
<key>FLTEnableWideGamut</key>
<true/>
```

to your info.plist

Answer (score 2):

> Does flutter support display p3 color profile?

No.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55092